# Deactivated user redirect to login from ajax request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter-3

Can anyone tell me the best practice to check if the user is activated and logged-in? And how can I handle it from ajax request?

If a user is deactivated, redirect to the login page via ajax request on a controller.

I'm making a helper function and calling it in the constructor.

But it not redirecting to the login if the user is deactivated and return "Status Code: 303 See Other"

In controller:

```
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('auth_helper');
    if (!auth())
    {
        redirect('login/login_panel');
    }
}
```

Helper function:

```
function auth()
{

    $CI =& get_instance();

    $user = true;
    if ($CI->session->userdata('user_id')) {
        $CI->load->model('users_model');
        $active = $CI->users_model->getActive($CI->session->userdata('user_id'));
        if ($active->active == '0' || $active->active == null) {
            $user = false;
        }
    } else {
        $user = false;
    }

    return $user;
}
```

Comment: you can't redirect from your controller directly if you're calling via ajax. You have to redirect in the front end part.

Answer (score 0):

i face same issue and i do following steps:

1- create a controller and check in index() function that user is logged or not.

2- in header or footer or sidebar (any static view file) of application make an ajax request each 5 second and check the index() function returns true or not

3- if returned value is false then redirect to login page,

```
class CheckLogin extends CI_Controller{
   function index(){
     if(isUserLogged()){
        return true;
     } else{ return false; }
   }
}
```

And In Front:

```
$ajax({
  url: 'CheckLogin',
  success: function (data){
     if(!data /* which means data is false*/)
     {  location.href = 'login.php'; }
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```php
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('auth_helper');
    if (!auth())
    {
        header('Location: login/login_panel');
        exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: No, it's not working for me. It fails with 302 and there is also a second call for login page in the network(console). But the browser doesn't redirect.